pronouncing Charles and other -ar words
If you look up US pronunciation of 'Charles' on youglish.com you'll notice that more often than not it is pronounced with rounded lips, like 'Chorles' (the fact that was brought to my attention by a guy from US whose name was Charles and who insisted that it was pronounced 'Chorles'). If you look up 'charcoal' or 'car' more often than not it is -ar, not -or (but still sometimes -or). What's the pattern here?

There are lots of different accents spoken in the USA, and vowel sounds are very variable.  There are probably some accents in which the vowel in Charles is rounded somewhat.  The examples I saw on youglish all use an unrounded vowel.  What you call "ar" an "or" is probably based on how the vowel that is spelled with that letter is pronounced in your language.

In Boston, the river is the Chahles. Notice at 28 sec into https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5apEctKwiD8 . Regional accents abound. [It took me some time to understand that "Max at school' was not a buddy, but what one gets on a "repawt cahd".]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"ch" /tʃ/ is normally pronounced with rounded lips, so maybe that's what you're seeing.

@StuartF, "roundedlips" for  /tʃ/ might be a regional thing, though not common where I've lived. Perhaps I'd dance a Csárdás (/ˈtʃɑːrdæʃ/), but never a /ˈtʃɔ:rdæʃ/.
